# What is the least total batch size for SyncBatchNorm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, mxnet, batch-normalization

For the normal `BatchNorm`, the least batch size per GPU is 2.

I wonder if I use the `SyncBatchNorm`, can I use `batch_size=1` for every GPU with more than a single GPU?

I.e, the `total_batch_size` is more than 1 but `batch_size_per_gpu` is 1.

I would appreciate answers for any deep learning framework, pytorch, tensorflow, mxnet, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PyTorch, using `batch_size_per_gpu=1` and more than one GPU is fine.